# How to get the image size to facebook comment image size in android

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

Now i am going on with pick of multiple images i have list of 5 image i have to reduce those image size to small as same as like facebook comment image.

Tried with below:

```
 Bitmap bitmapOriginal = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
          Bitmap bitmapsimplesize = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapOriginal,bitmapOriginal.getWidth() / 2, bitmapOriginal.getHeight() / 2, true); 
   viewHolder.galleryImage.setImageBitmapbitmapsimplesize
```

this cause me **null pointer** exeception.

Then move on with the below:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/images/image.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, blob);
byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);
```

this causes me **outofmemory error**.

Then moved on with some other method but no use

How can get the image size so small if anyone have idea please help to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [Bitmap decodeFile (String pathName, BitmapFactory.Options opts)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)) for that

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile("path", opts);
long size = opts.outHeight * opts.outWidth;
```

`opts.inJustDecodeBounds` means

> If set to true, the decoder will return null (no bitmap), but the out... fields will still be set, allowing the caller to query the bitmap without having to allocate the memory for its pixels.

Comment: let me try and know for u